# checking if a number is a prime

Tags: prime-numbers

I was reading Wikipedia, and it was given that "all primes are of the form 6k ± 1"  (other than 2 and 3), where k = 1,2,3,4,...

Is this statement correct? If yes, can we use this to test if a given number is a prime number? For instance, we can say that 41 is a prime number, since there exists an integer K (K >= 1), such that 6k - 1 = 41 ==> k = 7.

I am confused why this test cannot be used to test if a number is prime?

Thanks,
Sekhar

Comment: All primes $\neq 2,3$ are of the form $6k\pm 1$, but not all numbers of the form $6k\pm 1$ are primes.

Comment: for example 25 or 35

Comment: Thanks so much for answering

Comment: Please notice that comments are not for answering the question. Please consider posting these as answers, or someone else will do this.

Answer (score 1):

For $k\ge 1$ no prime can be of the form $6k$ (obvious), $6k+2=2(3k+1)$, $6k+3=3(2k+1)$, $6k+4=2(3k+2)$. There remains $6k+1$  and $6k+5=6(k+1)-1$.

Answer (score 1):

If a number can be in the form $6k\pm1$ "CAN" be a prime number but not always. A prime number $p>3$ can be always in this form. If you want a text to know if a number is prime you can use the Wilson's theorem : $(p-1)\equiv -1\pmod p$

Comment: Your statement of Wilson's theorem isn't right: it should say that $p$ is prime iff $(p-1)! \equiv -1$ (mod $p$). Wilson's theorem is not a practical test for primality.

Comment: @DomenicoVuono, you may want to edit your answer to reflect what have been discussed in the comments.